# Knockout tree - get all selected items in tree

Tags: arrays, knockout.js

[Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/barryman9000/ee43N/4/)

I have a tree structure of clients that I'm binding to an unordered list, and each client may or may not have a SubClient. I've added the ability to select an item in the list but now I cannot figure out how to loop through the tree and get an array of all the selected items.

In particular, this beast is where I'm having problems:

```
cp.GetSelectedClientsArray = function (clients) {
    var selected = [];
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(clients, function (item) {
        if (item.IsSelected()) {
            selected.push(item.ClientName());
        }
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(item.SubClient(), function (subItem) {
            if (subItem.IsSelected()) {
                selected.push(subItem.ClientName());
            }
            cp.GetSelectedClientsArray(subItem);
        });
    });
    console.log(selected);
    return selected;
};
```

After I toggle the IsSelected() observable I'd like to loop through the list and get an array with only the selected items.

I've written and re-written this more than a few times, and could really use some help. I'm not even sure how to write a recursive function that would work, because every time I call the function from within, it wipes out my "selected" array and setting it as a global variable keeps any item that has ever been selected in the array.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Is there a reason you are not adding/removing the selected clients to an observable array at the time you select in the _self.ToggleSelectedUser function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's recursive version

```
cp.GetSelectedClientsArray = function (clients) {
    var result = [];
    function GetSelected(clients){
        for (var i in clients){
            if(clients[i].IsSelected()){
                result.push(clients[i].ClientName());
            }
            GetSelected(clients[i].SubClient());
        }
    }
    GetSelected(clients);
    console.log(result);
    return result;
};
```

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ee43N/15/)

Answer (score 1):

Why walk on the clients list recursively when you can simply create a `SelectedClients` field on the View-Model, and remove/add to it upon toggling?

For example:

```
_self.SelectedClients = ko.observableArray([]);

_self.ToggleSelectedUser = function (data, event) {
    var toggle = !data.IsSelected();
    data.IsSelected(toggle);

    if (toggle)
        _self.SelectedClients.push(data.ClientName());
    else
        _self.SelectedClients.remove(data.ClientName());
};
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ee43N/7/).

**Update:**

As per your comment, when you do need to walk recursively on the tree, you can try something like this:

```
function AggregateSelectedClients(clients, results)
{
    results = results || [];
    if (!clients || !clients.length) return results;

    ko.unwrap(clients).forEach(function(v, i)
                    {
                    var selected = ko.unwrap(v.IsSelected);
                    var subClients = ko.unwrap(v.SubClient);

                    if (selected)
                        results.push(ko.unwrap(v.ClientName));

                    if (subClients && subClients.length)
                        AggregateSelectedClients(subClients, results);
                    });

    return results;
}
```

Comment: This solves the problem described, thanks. I know at some point I'm going to have to iterate over each item in my tree though. Any ideas how I'd accomplish this with a recursive function?

Comment: This was very helpful, but @GSerjo's answer is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to do, why not try something like this?

```
 _self.SelectedClient = ko.observableArray();
 _self.ToggleSelectedUser = function (data, event) {
        var toggle = !data.IsSelected();
        data.IsSelected(toggle);

        if(toggle === true) 
        { 
             _self.SelectedClient.push(data.ClientName()); 
        } 
        else 
        {
           _self.SelectedClient.remove(data.ClientName());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The selected children have to be added to the parent selection.

```
ko.utils.arrayForEach(item.SubClient(), function (subItem) {
   if (subItem.IsSelected()) {
      selected.push(subItem.ClientName());
   }       
   //cp.GetSelectedClientsArray(subItem);
   selected.push.apply(selected, cp.GetSelectedClientsArray(subItem));
});
```

**[See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ee43N/5/)**

I hope it helps.